# The request channel timed out attempting to send after 00:01:00 WCF

Tags: c#, wcf

I am implementing a WCF Console Application which communicate with another as well console application. the issue is that i want to increase the sending timeout

I have added the following xml in the config file but it seems that the entered data is not binding.

```
 <system.serviceModel>
  <behaviors>
  <serviceBehaviors>
    <behavior name="mexBehavior">
      <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
    </behavior>
  </serviceBehaviors>
</behaviors>
<services>
  <service name="SocketCommunicator.WcfCommunicator.WcfCommunicator" behaviorConfiguration="mexBehavior">
    <endpoint address="WcfCommunicator" binding="basicHttpBinding" contract="SocketCommunicator.WcfCommunicator.IWcfCommunicator" 
              bindingConfiguration="longTimeRunningService"></endpoint>
    <host>
      <baseAddresses>
        <add baseAddress="http://localhost:87355/" />
      </baseAddresses>
    </host>
  </service>
</services>
 <bindings>
      <basicHttpBinding>
          <binding name="longTimeRunningService" 
                   openTimeout="00:30:00"
                   closeTimeout="00:30:00"
                   sendTimeout="00:30:00"
                   receiveTimeout="00:30:00">
          </binding>
      </basicHttpBinding>
  </bindings>
 </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Is it a standalone windows service or  an IIS hosted web application? And what is the equivalent configuration on the client?

Comment: it is only a standalone windows service. i didn't do any thing in client just only connect it with the service base URL. everything is actually working fine, but i have a function which located within this windows service application in which this function do multiple tasks which takes quite long more than a minute, in which it end up causing this error  on the client side hence the client side is waiting for the coming back response

Comment: at the being is my configuration is correct for extending  sendTimeout ?

Comment: You can try setting the timeout to your desired amount in the sendTimeout property, for example sendTimeout="00:01:00"

Comment: How To extend this send time out. is it supposed to be configured from client side or server side or both

Comment: Sendtimeout needs to be configured on both the server and client.

Comment: can you please show me an example on how to configure the extended send time out for an IIS hosted net.core application which represents the client side

Comment: Check the official documents : [Configuring Timeout Values on a Binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/configuring-timeout-values-on-a-binding)

Comment: this is exactly how i configured the server side. only left the client side configuration.  the client is an IIS hosted web application( .Net Core Web )

Comment: You first configure on the server and then run it.

Comment: i configured it on the server. i didn't understand what you mean by then return it?